# Hibernate Envers find in OneToMany JoinTable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Hi I'm forcing problem with Envers. Every class extends BaseEntity that contains @GeneratedAuto id's etc. Have two entities:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class HandballInjury extends Injury {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "HandballDictionaryFact")
  private List<HandballDictionaryFact> handballDictionaryFacts = new ArrayList<HandballDictionaryFact>();
  private HandballTimeOfInjury timeOfInjury;

  ...
}
```

And

```
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "handballDictionaryFact")
public class HandballDictionaryFact extends DictionaryFact{
  ...
}
```

*Both parents have @Audited annotation. My problem is that when I'm using AuditEntity find method on HandballInjury it returns correct injury with all dictionaryFacts which belong to injury but without taking care about revisionId. In database everything is saved correctly. I think that if table is joined then envers look just if id's are correct without looking at revision. Hibernate Envers version: 5.1.0.Final

Edit 1:

I found that I'm not opening new session by SessionFactory.openSession(). Because of this envers was entering into 1 LevelCache to get data. I've repaired that but its not helping. Thats how query is initiated:

```
  result = getReader().find(HandballInjury.class, ((HandballInjury) object).getId(), revisionNumber);
```

Maybe I should write own query?

I've noticed that query below returns also all entities from HandballDictionaryFacts_aud instead of with specified revisionNumber.

```
 List<HandballDictionaryFact> dictionaryFact = getReader().createQuery()
                .forEntitiesAtRevision(HandballDictionaryFact.class, revisionNumber).getResultList();
```

Edit 2:
I found that find query is looking for handballDictionaryFact with RevNumber less or equal to handballInjury.RevNumber. My question is now can I force envers to look only equal? Part of Query:

```
        and handballdi1_.REV=(
        select
            max(handballdi2_.REV) 
        from
            dictionaryfact_AUD handballdi2_ 
        where
            handballdi2_.DTYPE='HandballDictionaryFact' 
            and handballdi2_.REV<=?
            and handballdi1_.id=handballdi2_.id
    )
```

Query from first edit also checks if revNumber is less or equal.

Comment: Envers should be applying the `REV` predicate so that any associations to the aggregate root, in this case `HandballInjury`, would be equal-to or less-than that of the aggregate root.  If you're absolutely sure it isn't doing that, please open a JIRA ticket and report the problem with a simple test case that reproduces the error.

Comment: After debugging I found that envers takes data from firstlevelcache instead of database. But have no idea how to change that.

Comment: You're saying its taking the data from the Session's 1LC or Envers' internal 1LC as they're two different things. Could you update your post with the query and how you're observing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that when I'm using AuditEntity find method on HandballInjury it returns correct injury with all dictionaryFacts which belong to injury but without taking care about revisionId. In database everything is saved correctly. I think that if table is joined then envers look just if id's are correct without looking at revision.

That isn't possible because of how the audit tracking actually works.

If you look at the audit tables, you'll notice that the entity's primary key is supplimented in the audit tables with the revision number in many cases to allow for multiple entries for the same entity primary key.

```
+----+-----+---------+---------+
| ID | REV | REVTYPE | DATA    |
+----+-----+---------+---------+
|  1 |   1 |       0 | Initial |
+----+-----+---------+---------+
|  1 |   2 |       1 | Updated |
+----+-----+---------+---------+
|  1 |   3 |       2 |         |
+----+-----+---------+---------+
```

As you can see in this illustration, the table here has 3 rows for the same entity primary key where the entity was inserted (REVTYPE=0), updated (REVTYPE=1), and deleted (REVTYPE=2).

Should this table be associated with another entity, we also need to take into account the `REV` value in order to make sure that the association is correct based on that point in time when the revision was created.

Lets consider another entity that points to the above table's ID=1.  If we don't take `REV` into account, then we have no idea how we should populate the `DATA` field on the associated audit entity instance.  Should it be `Initial` or `Updated`?

That is another reason the `REV` field must be considered.

> found that I'm not opening new session by SessionFactory.openSession(). Because of this envers was entering into 1 LevelCache to get data. I've repaired that but its not helping.

I believe its important to clarify here that Envers uses its own L1C implementation that is independent of the one that Hibernate Session uses.

Envers uses its own implementation because the objects which it instantiates are not *real managed entities*, but instead just constructed objects that use the entity object layout to represent the state of that entity at a given revision in time.

I'm not exactly clear why you had to change anything related to Session management unless your code is doing something else obscure.

```
HandballInjury injuryAtRevision = getReader()
  .find( HandballInjury.class, handballInjury.getId(), revisionNumber );
```

The above query will basically look to see if the Envers L1C contains an instance of `HandballInjury` for that given primary key and revision.  If so, it returns it; otherwise it fetches it from the database.

The returned instance will represent the state of `HandballInjury` at the time when the specified `revisionNumber` value was generated, including any audited associations.

> Maybe I should write own query?

Why, you haven't clarified precisely the issue here.  The query does exactly what its intended to do, as described above.

> I've noticed that query below returns also all entities from HandballDictionaryFacts_aud instead of with specified revisionNumber.

```
 List<HandballDictionaryFact> dictionaryFact = getReader().createQuery()
   .forEntitiesAtRevision( HandballDictionaryFact.class, revisionNumber )
   .getResultList();
```

And that is expected behavior.

If we assume we had two facts, one created at revision 1 and another at revision 2 and the above used `revisionNumber=2`, then at that moment in time, you have 2 entities defined, do you not?

I could see improving the java-doc here to make it more clear, but that is the expected behavior none-the-less.

> Edit 2: I found that find query is looking for handballDictionaryFact with RevNumber less or equal to handballInjury.RevNumber. My question is now can I force envers to look only equal

If you wish to be explicit and obtain entities at a specific revision beyond the default scope of the query, you can add additional predicates to return that type of result.

```
 List<HandballDictionaryFact> dictionaryFact = getReader().createQuery()
   .forEntitiesAtRevision( HandballDictionaryFact.class, revisionNumber )
   .add( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq( 2 ) )
   .getResultList();
```

Taking the same assumption as before, a fact created at revision 1 and another at revision 2, this would return a single entry that contained the fact created specifically in revision 2.